# All output functions of a truth table

Tags: propositional-logic

> http://www.cim.mcgill.ca/~langer/273/3-notes.pdf
>   [image]

I can name one more: XNOR. But besides these, what other output functions are there?

Comment: Don't use images as main content of your post. This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired; [we don't like that](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/752/should-we-do-anything-about-questions-that-are-just-a-scan-of-a-problem-in-their). Please transcribe text and mathematics (note that you can [use LaTeX](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands)).

Comment: There is a classification of all 16 binary boolean functions in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table#Truth_table_for_all_binary_logical_operators).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you try to come up with a new output function, which you call $A\otimes B$, with new, custom behaviour. You will have to come up with four values: $0\otimes 0, 0 \otimes 1, 1 \otimes 0, 1 \otimes 1$. One arbitrary example is: $0\otimes 0 = 0, 0 \otimes 1 = 1, 1 \otimes 0 = 0, 1 \otimes 1 = 0$. Any sequence of zeroes and ones will do (this is the answer to your question). So you can write a string of four zeroes or ones, and that will represent your function. For example, my function is represented with $0100$. How many such strings are there? Well, try enumerating them: $0000,0001,0010,0011,\ldots$ Hence the remark that there are $2^{4}=16$ possible functions.

Not all of these functions are equally useful. The example I gave is equivalent to $A\otimes B = \neg A \wedge B$. In fact, every (binary) output function can be written as a combination of the three functions $\neg, \wedge, \vee$, i.e. NOT, OR and AND.

Consider functions that use three arguments, $A,B,C$. The truth table of such a function has $8$ entries, so there are a total of $2^{8}=256$ functions on three variables. Can you find a formula for the number of functions on $n$ variables? The example functions in your excerpt are all examples of *commutative* functions, which are functions $\circ$ where $A\circ B = B \circ A$ for every value of $A$ and $B$. Can you think of a noncommutative function?

Comment: I thought all 16 are useful defined functions (like AND, OR, etc). Thanks for clearing this up. Of course, it can be useful depending what sort of conditions i have in my problem. Also, are there any non-commutative operation?

Comment: Glad to help. Of course, all functions have some use, and usefulness is subjective. One strong case for the usefullness of AND, OR, NOT is that together, these three operations are *universal*, meaning that they can express any other function (although not necessarily succinctly). 

Is the function $A\otimes B$ that I gave commutative?

Comment: Nice one. It's non-commutative.